# Adding new member to CsvProvider type in F#

Tags: csv, f#, record, type-providers

I'm reading a CSV file in F# with CsvProvider from FSharp.Data. Is there a way to add new (calculated) columns without transforming it into an entirely new type?

```
open FSharp.Data

type Person = CsvProvider<"persons.csv">
let personData = Person.Load "persons.csv"
```

If `Person` has a member called `YearOfBirth` then is it possible to add a new member to it called `Age` that would have the calculated value of `(DateTime.Now.Year - YearOfBirth)` for all CSV rows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what you want, but this may work:

```
type Person.Row with
    member this.Age = DateTime.Now.Year - this.YearOfBirth
```

Comment: It does work, it's exactly what I wanted. Thank you, I didn't know records can be extended this way in F#.